# SSIS and Script Component - WebReference problem

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssdt, ssis-2012

Within my SSIS package-dataflow I have a script component and within this component whenever I add a Web reference and close editor, script component gives me

> "Validation error. Data Flow Task Script Component [1]: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully."

I can successfully build from the editor, but error resides there.

How can I solve this problem.

Ps: I am using SSDT for VS2012.

Comment: My general experience has been that when I receive the "binary code not found" message, my code didn't actually compile. Since you provided no details, my only proposal would be to add a new script component as the source, have it emit a single row (hardcoded values). Once that's working, add your web reference but don't actually use it. Does it still work? Incrementally add functionality into the component until it's finished or until you've identified what's breaking it. For us to help, we'll need to see your code and ideally access to the web service - or a comparable substitute.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned, I do nothing fancy; edit script component (fresh, nothing coded), add web reference, and do nothing else, close editor, back to editor and it immediately puts red sign with the mentioned error. When I build it before closing, it builds without error. When I add same reference with identical steps with in my web application, it runs fine.